# How to obtain dynamic google map url of a specific map (I have static map url)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I have the below static google map url. just want to know the equivalent for dynamic map.

[Static Google Map URL](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn%20Bridge,New%20York,NY&zoom=14&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap%20&markers=color%3ablue%7Clabel%3aS%7C40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color%3agreen%7Clabel%3aG%7C40.711614,-74.012318%20&markers=color%3ared%7Ccolor%3ared%7Clabel%3aC%7C40.718217,-73.998284&sensor=false)

I am not sure if it is v2 or v3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `center` by `q` and just swap the base URLs:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn%20Bridge,New%20York,NY&zoom=14&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap%20&markers=color%3ablue|label%3aS|40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color%3agreen|label%3aG|40.711614,-74.012318%20&markers=color%3ared|color%3ared|label%3aC|40.718217,-73.998284&sensor=false
```

to:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Brooklyn%20Bridge,New%20York,NY&zoom=14&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap%20&markers=color%3ablue|label%3aS|40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color%3agreen|label%3aG|40.711614,-74.012318%20&markers=color%3ared|color%3ared|label%3aC|40.718217,-73.998284&sensor=false
```

Comment: Thanks, too fast response. Is it possible to create one with the same appearance? like the static one has the map itself only.