# How to display non static google map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have the following code snippets built by watching a few tutorials and reading official documentation:

```
    HTML:

    <div class="map-area">
    <img id="fancybutton" class="icon map_icon" src="../location.png" />
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </div>

jQuery:

    $('.map_icon').click(function(){

            var mapOptions = new google.maps.Map( mapDiv, {

                    center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
                    zoom: 8

            } );

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);


    });
```

I does work, however it displays static map as following:

```
<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/StaticMapService.GetMapImage?1m2&amp;1i59992&amp;2i39244&amp;2e1&amp;3u8&amp;4m2&amp;1u400&amp;2u400&amp;5m5&amp;1e0&amp;5sda-DK&amp;6sus&amp;10b1&amp;12b1&amp;token=46934" style="width: 400px; height: 400px;">
```

How can I display a regular google map that a user could zoom in/out etc?

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: you can use a &z=nn  http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/115165

Comment: just replace `center` with `q` [How to obtain dynamic google map url of a specific map (I have static map url)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102264/how-to-obtain-dynamic-google-map-url-of-a-specific-map-i-have-static-map-url)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need: Refer https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/:

```
    <html>

  <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript"> 

  $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('.map_icon').click(function(){ 
           initialize();
        });
  });
  function initialize() {
    var mapProp = {
      center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
      zoom:5,
      mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
  }
  </script>

  <body>
    <div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
   <a id="fancybutton" class="icon map_icon">Load Map</a>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is not what I am asking for. In fact, I was asking FOR the scrollwheel by having a map to display not as an IMG.

Comment: make scrollwheel true for zooming on the map dude...I saw you the basic script..you may change whatever you want in this map by setting proper properties

Comment: I did try to set it to true. But the map still displays as an `img` which obviously cannot be zoomed in/out and moved around. So this solution definatelly does not help my problem.

Comment: Thank you a lot for getting this far. The map now shows with all the functions needed. However, if you looked at my code, the map was displaying only on `map-icon` click and with your example, it displays on load.

Comment: All you had to do is dive into the Maps docs a little and you would have been able to copy a snippet from their examples.

Comment: @WpDoe : Ok i have updated code above..where you can load map on click eevent..have a look..